# Can I extend a Java class in Oracle's JDK7 JSR223 JavaScript engine?

Tags: java, javascript, jsr223

I'm trying to write JavaScript that will define a class that extends an existing Java class, called from a JSR223 `ScriptEngine`.  I know that [JavaAdapter works for an Interface, but not a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/#jsengine).

```
ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
js.eval("new java.lang.Runnable {run: function() { ... } }"); // works
js.eval("new java.util.TimerTask {run: function() { ... } }"); // throws
```

I know that's what the docs say I should expect.  I also know that once I can switch to Nashorn, all this will go away and I'll have lovely access to `Java.extend()`, etc., but for the time being I'm stuck with JDK7.

*Given all that*, is there any way to do this?  I think my fallback will be switching directly to Mozilla's native Rhino bindings, but I'd prefer to keep this as abstract as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.  I was under the impression that I could only implement an interface, but it turns out that you can also extend a *concrete* class -- only *abstract* classes throw the error I described.

```
ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
js.eval("new java.lang.Runnable() {run: function() { ... } }"); // works
js.eval("new java.lang.Thread() {run: function() { ... } }"); // works
js.eval("new java.util.TimerTask() {run: function() { ... } }"); // throws
```

This is good enough for my needs -- the docs could definitely be clearer, though!

Answer (score 0):

What does it throw?

```
jjs> var tt = new java.util.TimerTask {run: function() { print("hello"); }}
jjs> tt.run();
hello
null
```

I usually skip TimerTask altogether

```
// Daemon flag seems to be ignored.
var timer = new java.util.Timer(false);
timer.schedule(function() print("Hello"), 1000);

// Give timer a chance to run before exit.
java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: I wasn't actually trying to make a timer, I was just looking for a simple example of a class that doesn't work.  It throws `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException` with the message "first arg should be interface Class: class java.util.TimerTask is interface or abstract".